# Breadth-first search (BFS) for binary tree

Tags: binary-trees

It is pretty simple to implement a DFS algorithm for a binary tree but what about BFS for binary trees? I tried to adapt the BFS algorithm for ordered tree, this is the result:

[image]

I presume that better solutions are possible. Could someone suggest a  better solutions?

Comment: I assume here that $Q.enqueue(T)$, inserts the root of the tree. If that's the case, I think the only problem is that you are inserting the left and right child of $T$ instead of $u$.

Comment: My fault, it's a typo. Thank you, I'll update the code

Comment: is $Queue$  $Q$ meant to create a new queue? If so then that's a problem. You need to pass the root of the tree as well as a queue to $BFS$

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Question edited. I think I expressed myself badly, my goal was to present a possible solution and compare myself with other users in order to find possible alternative and better solutions than mine